# How do I add Armadillo to Visual Studio code 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, armadillo

I have tried every stack overflow answer but most of them are for the older versions of VS Code. I have the armadillo file extracted from .tar via 7zip and have tried to copy the files manually to VS Code folders but nothing seems to work. Also tried on Codeblocks added the .lib to the linker but nothing works.

Armadillo - http://arma.sourceforge.net/download.html

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Install `msys2` and `gcc`/`clang` (optionally, `gdb`/`lldb`) over it, then run this command `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-armadillo`. Then add `-larmadillo` to `"args"` key of `tasks.json`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I installed and ran the command but how do I add -larmadillo? Which tasks.json would it be? Thanks for your help

Comment: Take help from the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) at configuring the intellisense (Do not install Mingw-64 again, just add the msys2 bin to PATH). Well you can compile your file even without configuring that. Simply add it during compiling. `g++ file.cpp -o out.exe -larmadillo`.

Comment: Great, thx again